# UINavigationController Problem

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

In a view Controller I am adding a UINavigationController and it has around 20-30 pixels on top of it. It doesnt fit the navigationCOntroller properly. For soem reason it adds the subview 20-30 px below

```
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor grayColor];
UnitViewController *unitController = [[UnitViewController alloc] init];
[navController pushViewController:unitController animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:navController.view];
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a full screen app then perhaps the UnitViewController's view is not setup correctly. It may be assuming presence of status bar and leaving room for it.

Comment: self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);